# How to ensure a Pharo VM is running with systemd

Tags: virtualization, systemd, services

I'm aiming to write an application in the Smalltalk fork Pharo and run this on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Pharo runs as a VM environment, using a Pharo image which runs the particular application. When deploying Pharo it's important to get the VM running and monitor that it hasn't crashed or frozen.

The [Pharo Enterprise book](https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/EnterprisePharoBook/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/DeploymentWeb/DeployForProduction.html) advises using the `monit` utility to do this, although the instructions given are based around init scripts.

Is there a better approach using systemd?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [systemd service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), in particular [Restart](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) and its conditionals (to decide when an abort should be restarted or not).

Furthermore the doc you listed certain actions to be taken as prep/folow-up to a restart. For that [ExecStartPre](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) and co might help.

The workload as-is might not be suited for it (yet), but generally in addition you'd want to consider is to have the service to keep some [keep-alive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#WatchdogSec=) up and also check on that.